# Error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Здравствуйте.

Решил попробовать себя в создании приложений под андроид. ОС Windows XP SP3, древнее железо, камень Athlon 2800+.

- Установил Eclipse и [плагин](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html). Все получилось без проблем.
- Установил JDK и JRE.
- Установил Android SDK

Eclipse не хочет запускаться. Вот что в логе пишет

```
!SESSION 2011-08-10 18:15:52.625 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-08-10 18:15:56.468
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (52).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    ...

Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Could not read metadata for 'C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.root\3.tree'.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreTree(SaveManager.java:1005)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    ... 36 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException(C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/3.tree)[567]: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    ...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-08-10 18:15:56.500
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    ...
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (52).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Could not read metadata for 'C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.root\3.tree'.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreTree(SaveManager.java:1005)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    ... 36 more
```

---

Может кто помочь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо установить соответствующий JDK: [Java SE Development Kit 7 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html).

Comment: 32-х битная система и есть x86. Смело качайте и ставьте.

Comment: А что такое x32? Чем оно отличается от x86?

Comment: тупанул жестоко)

Comment: Петрович, х86 - это наименование архитектуры 32-х битного проца  Intel 80x86.